# userData is not defined under useState React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks

My code is malfunctioning and showing **TypeError: userData is undefined** error. I am taking data from MongoDB to show on the website.
**{userData.name}** is creating the trouble. set user data part of UseState is working fine and am getting the data in the console from MongoDB. The error seems to be in the frontend part.

**Code:-**

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MetaTags from "react-meta-tags";
import { BreadcrumbsItem } from "react-breadcrumbs-dynamic";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import LayoutOne from "../../layouts/LayoutOne";
import Breadcrumb from "../../wrappers/breadcrumb/Breadcrumb";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";



const MyAccount = ({ location }) => {
  const { pathname } = location;
  

  const history = useHistory();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

    const callAccount = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('/myaccount', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        
        },
        credentials: "include"
      });

      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      setUserData(data);
      
      if (!res.status === 200)
      {
        const error = new Error(res.error);
        throw error;
        }

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      history.push('/login')
      
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    callAccount();
  
  }, []);


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MetaTags>
        <title>Flone | My Account</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Compare page of flone react minimalist eCommerce template."
        />
      </MetaTags>
      <BreadcrumbsItem to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}>Home</BreadcrumbsItem>
      <BreadcrumbsItem to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + pathname}>
        My Account
      </BreadcrumbsItem>
      <LayoutOne headerTop="visible">
        {/* breadcrumb */}
        <Breadcrumb />
        <div className="myaccount-area pb-80 pt-100">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="ml-auto mr-auto col-lg-9">
                <div className="myaccount-wrapper">
                  <form method="GET">
                  <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                    <Card className="single-my-account mb-20">
                      <Card.Header className="panel-heading">
                        <Accordion.Toggle variant="link" eventKey="0">
                          <h3 className="panel-title">
                            <span>1 .</span> My account information{" "}
                          </h3>
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                      </Card.Header>
                      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                        <Card.Body>
                          <div className="myaccount-info-wrapper">
                            <div className="account-info-wrapper">
                              
                                <h5>Your Personal Details { userData.name}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                              <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div className="billing-info">
                                    <label>First Name </label>
                                  <input type="text" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div className="billing-info">
                                  <label>Last Name</label>
                                  <input type="text" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <div className="billing-info">
                                  <label>Email Address</label>
                                  <input type="email" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div className="billing-info">
                                  <label>Telephone</label>
                                  <input type="text" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div className="billing-info">
                                  <label>Fax</label>
                                  <input type="text" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          
                          </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                      </Accordion.Collapse>
                    </Card>
                    <Card className="single-my-account mb-20">
                      <Card.Header className="panel-heading">
                        <Accordion.Toggle variant="link" eventKey="1">
                          <h3 className="panel-title">
                            <span>2 .</span> Change your password
                          </h3>
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                      </Card.Header>
                      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                        <Card.Body>
                          <div className="myaccount-info-wrapper">
                            <div className="account-info-wrapper">
                              <h4>Change Password</h4>
                              <h5>Your Password</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                              <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <div className="billing-info">
                                  <label>Password</label>
                                  <input type="password" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <div className="billing-info">
                                  <label>Password Confirm</label>
                                  <input type="password" />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          
                          </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                      </Accordion.Collapse>
                    </Card>
                    <Card className="single-my-account mb-20">
                      <Card.Header className="panel-heading">
                        <Accordion.Toggle variant="link" eventKey="2">
                          <h3 className="panel-title">
                            <span>3 .</span> Modify your address book entries{" "}
                          </h3>
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                      </Card.Header>
                      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="2">
                        <Card.Body>
                          <div className="myaccount-info-wrapper">
                            <div className="account-info-wrapper">
                              <h4>Address Book Entries</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="entries-wrapper">
                              <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                  <div className="entries-info text-center">
                                    <p>John Doe</p>
                                    <p>Paul Park </p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amet</p>
                                    <p>NYC</p>
                                    <p>New York</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="billing-back-btn">
                              <div className="billing-btn">
                                <button type="submit">Continue</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                      </Accordion.Collapse>
                    </Card>
                    </Accordion>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </LayoutOne>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

MyAccount.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.object
};

export default MyAccount;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the initial of `userData` is `undefined`. Just update it with an object

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> const [userData, serUserData] = useState();
> ```

The initial value is the argument you pass to `useState`.

You haven't passed any value, so it is initially `undefined`.

---

At some point in the future the Ajax request will come back and you might call `setUserData` to assign a different value, but by then you've tried to read `userData.name` and thrown an exception.

You need to account for that in your code. A typical approach would be to do something like:

```
if (!userData) {
    return <ALoadingComponent />
}
return /* what you have now */
```